# WPF MaterialDesignFilledComboBox - Center HintText vertically

Tags: wpf, combobox, material-design, hint

I have this ComboBox using the `MaterialDesignFilledComboBox` style.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeData}"
          Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFilledComboBox}"
          materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Some hint text"
</ComboBox>
```

Notice the assignment of the `materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Some hint text"` property.
When I have not chosen an item in the ComboBox's drop-down-menu, the `Hint` property ("Some hint text") is the only visible text in the ComboBox. That is fine.
Above the Hint, there is an "unused space".
If I select an item in the drop-down-menu, the "unused space" is occupied by the `Hint` and showing the "Some hint text".

**Question**
My designer dislike the "above space" when there is no item selected in the drop-down-menu.
Is it possible to center the `Hint` vertically in the ComboBox when there is **no item selected**?

**My findings**
Looking into the `MaterialDesignFilledComboBox`'s template ([MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBoxTemplate](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ComboBox.xaml)).
I found the `SmartHint` control at rows 374 - 397. This control seem to be the placeholder for the Hint.
If I add this style as a resource to the ComboBox, I have some limitied control of the `SmartHint` object in my ComboBox.
For instance:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeData}"
          Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFilledComboBox}"
          materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Some hint text"
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="materialDesign:SmartHint">
            <Setter Property="VirtualizingPanel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

The setter with the `Visibility = Collapsed` actually works.
The setters of the `VerticalAlignment` and the `VerticalContentAlignment` properties don't work. Even if they would work, they would not given me the exact result I want, but prove that I can control the position of the control in some way.

Any suggestions?

/BR
Steffe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `HintAssist.IsFloating` attached property of the `ComboBox` to `false`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeData}"
          Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFilledComboBox}"
          materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="False"
          materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Some hint text" />
```

You could set it conditionally depending on whether an item is selected using a `Style`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeData}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Some hint text">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFilledComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating" Value="True" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating" Value="False" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

> Thanks to @mm8 I found a way to partially solve this problem...But there is a problem with the graphics of the ComboBox
> When I select the first item in the drop-down-menu, both the hint text and the text of the selected item, get all merged/mangled together into an unreadable mess.

That's a flaw of the third-party control.

You could work around it by handling the `SelectionChanged` and programmatically call the `ApplyTemplate` method of the `SmartHint`:

```
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
    HintAssist.SetIsFloating(cmb, cmb.SelectedItem != null);
    SmartHint smartHint = FindVisualChild<SmartHint>(cmb);
    if (smartHint != null)
    {
        smartHint.ApplyTemplate();
    }
}

private static T FindVisualChild<T>(Visual visual) where T : Visual
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual); i++)
    {
        Visual child = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, i);
        if (child != null)
        {
            T correctlyTyped = child as T;
            if (correctlyTyped != null)
            {
                return correctlyTyped;
            }

            T descendent = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (descendent != null)
            {
                return descendent;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

**XAML**:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeData}"
          SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"
          Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFilledComboBox}"
          materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="False"
          materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Some hint text" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That somewhat worked.
I have tried to set the IsFloating depending on the value of the SelectedItem property in the ComboBox. But that kinda worked. Please see my own answer of this topic.

Comment: @Mc_Topaz: Please see my edit for how to use a `Style` to set the property conditionally.

Comment: I tried you solution but I get the same problem of the Hint's text is merged with the SelectedItem's text :'(

Comment: That's a flaw of the third-party control I am afraid.

Comment: @Mc_Topaz: See my second edit for a solution.

Comment: @mm6: Thank you!
It worked now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Padding property

```
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 -10 0 0" />
```

Comment: Thank for the suggestion.
But it didn't effect the Hint's position in any way.

Comment: This is strange. The hint changes the position in my case. Maybe you have VerticalAligment = Top. This may interfere with.